# Automatic Scroll in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using an EditText in which the text is filled programaticaly, when users performs some action (consider this like a chat window).
Now when the text has filled the complete window, a scrollbar appears, but the user has to manually scroll it to see the latest chat (at the bottom).
Would it be possible to scroll it automatically to the latest chat ?
PS: I'm using an EditText and not a ScrollView

Comment: Sorry..it's EditText.
Have corrected now

Comment: Try to in Edit text write android:scrollbars="vertical"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this

`android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: EditText a  = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);           
a.setText("abcdefg");  
Editable b = a.getText();  
a.setSelection(b.length());

Comment: finally this solution and your comment worked for me. thank you so much. upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I think its not good to show chat conversation in EditText. Its easy to display chat conversations in a **ListView**. See the **BluetoothChat** example available at Android Developers website, here they used ListView for displaying chat conversation. [Check this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.html)

If you pay attention to understand the code in the above link, your problem will be solved. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Will check this link
The problem however, got solved by using android:ellipsize="end".

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, I have used `android:ellipsize="end"`